# Android vs iOS: create Preferences-like layout for non-preferences screens on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I come from iOS development where we have `UITableViewCell`, which is great for making vertical lists of content. A cell contains a primary and secondary label as well as an icon.

I've been looking for something similar on Android, and it seems like Preferences gives me exactly what I want. When I create a preferences page in Android, it's really easy to create a nice-looking layout from XML. Using the following simple XML code, I can get a vertical list of items (like `UITableView` in iOS) that has a nice icon on the left side, a user interface element on the right side (the switch), a properly sized and aligned title, and a nice animation when I tap the preference.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="setting_toggle"
        android:title="@string/setting_toggle"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting_toggle"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="setting_toggle2"
        android:title="@string/setting_toggle2"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting_toggle2"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

However, if I want to use a similar layout outside of Preferences (in my case, for a Menu screen that links to other pages), it seems much more difficult to get such a simple layout. I tried to do this with TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tablerow_1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This achieves the on-tap animation and centers the text vertically. But, my goal is to mimic the appearance of the preferences page, so there is a long way to go:

1. The default font of the text view is different from the default font of the preference.
2. The default row size is different.
3. There's no icon property on the text view nor the table row element.
4. There isn't an easy way to put another element on the right side (like a switch or secondary text view)

I find it hard to believe that Android would create an easy-to-use API like Preferences, then make it available for only one of the many situations where it would be useful. So, what am I missing? Is there a more widely usable preferences-like API that I'm just not aware of, or should I just use the Preferences API for non-preferences screens like menus?

Comment: You're missing ListView and RecyclerView.  TableLayout is a rare usecase-  it should only be used for relatively small tables of columnar data.  The above two are more equivalent of iOS's UiTableView.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with custom views in it.

1. You have to declare `ListView` in your activity/fragment layout.
2. You have to create xml layout where you define your row.
3. You have to create an adapter to insert data to your `ListView`.

For more you can look there: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html